# Termcolor working in VSC and not working in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm

I am trying to print some lines to terminal in red it works perfectly fine in VSC however PyCharm terminal seems to ignore it and prints everything in white

```
from termcolor import colored

print(f'{colored("test test test test", "red")}')
```

[Result from PyCharm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEYnq.jpg)
[Result from VSC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zfp0m.jpg)

I tried "Emulate terminal in output console" in Pycharm. In result i received this kind of result:
←[31mtest test test test←[0m